# bayes theorem clarification meeting parents

Tags: bayes-theorem

Question:

90% likelihood to meet her parents will happen tonight and it will be only held at three places, (C),  (N), (S) with the same probability. You have been to (C) and (N) but you haven't found the parents.
What is the probability that you see the parents at (S)?

From the question since there is a 90% likelihood to meet there is a 10% not to meet

I know I need to use Bayes theorem:

and trying to find the $P(\text{seeing parents at (S)}|\text{parents not at (C) and (S)})$

$P(\text{seeing parents at (S)} = 0.3$  from the question

but i am unsure how to proceed to find

$P(\text{parents not at (C) and (S)})$

and

$P(\text{parents not at (C) and (S)})|P(\text{seeing parents at (S)})$

to finish the bayes theorem

Comment: This is difficult to read. If English is not your native language you may want to re-write it in your language. Bayes' Theorem is common enough that someone may understand.

Comment: Im not too sure which particular part of the post is difficult to read in English

Answer (score 1):

$$ P( S | \text{not C and not N})=\frac{P(S) P(\text{not C or N} | S)}{P(S) P(\text{not C or N} | S) + P(\text{not S} | \text{not C or N} )} $$

For $P(S)$, you also have to multiply by that $0.9$ probability of the parents actually arriving. $$P(S) = 0.9 \times 0.3 $$ Clearly, $$P(\text{not C or N}| S) =1 $$ and $$P(\text{not S}|\text{not C or N} )=\frac{P(\text{not S,C,N })}{P(\text{not C or N})} =\frac{0.1}{0.9\cdot 0.3 +0.1}$$